# passing jsp page form input values as arguements to java method

Tags: java, jsp

I have a jsp page `test.jsp`
In that I  have a `HTML form` with 2 inputs. On click of submit button I need to pass those 5 input values to a JAVA method.

```
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
Submit : <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

I have not specified any action for the form.I do not want to use a servlet also

If I click on the submit button the `firstname` and `lastname` values should be passed as arguements to a java method in the same jsp file. it is the below method.

```
void setValues(String firstname, String lastname){
code to set values
}
```

Thank you

Comment: setValues(param.getString("firstname"),param.getString("lastname"));

Comment: You may be mixing things here. The click is on the client/browser side, whereas all Java/JSP is evaluated on the server side. Thus you can't really "pass ... arguments to java method in the same jsp file". Do see @Makky's answer for how to obtain the params on the server side though.

Answer (score 0):

You can get parameters values as

```
String firstname=request.getParameter("firstname");
String lastname=request.getParameter("lastname");

//call your method now

testClass.setValues(firstname,lastname);
```